# Block all windows with MessageBox.Show()

Tags: c#, wpf, windows

I'm currently working on a WPF app which has multiple windows. From the "main" window, you should be able to close the entire app. Before the app will be closed, the client wants it to show a dialog box which basically asks "are you sure you want to close the app" and blocks every other window until the user answers.

I'm currently using MessageBox.Show() to create this dialog box, but for some reason it only blocks the main window.

Here's the simplest example of what I'm talking about; if you create a WPF window with two buttons:

```
private void openChildWindowButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
  var window = new ChildWindow();
  window.Show();
}

private void openDialogButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
  MessageBox.Show(this, "This should freeze all other windows");
}
```

Opening a dialog will completely freeze the first window. If you click on it or attempt any sort of interaction, the OS makes a "ding!" sound and flashes the border on the message  box. But all of the other windows you've opened can be clicked, moved, resized, etc., and that's what I want to prevent.

Comment: Pass in the main window as the parent parameter to `Show()`.

Comment: That seems to have no effect. I'll throw it in the OP code sample just for completeness though

Comment: I suppose this might be a bit convoluted by why not just make your own little form with a label on it, hide the Maximize/Minimize/Close buttons, and make the constructor take a string. Set the label's text to that string and then throw on some Ok/Cancel buttons?

Comment: Well, I'm hoping to avoid creating a custom window that mimics a MessageBox, but it might just come down to something like that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As it turns out, there *is* a way to do this, but it's not pretty. It involves using the WinForms version of `MessageBox` and passing an undocumented option as the last property.

```
var result = System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("Are you sure you want to exit this app?", "Exit", System.Windows.Forms.MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, System.Windows.Forms.MessageBoxIcon.Question, System.Windows.Forms.MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button2, (System.Windows.Forms.MessageBoxOptions)8192 /*MB_TASKMODAL*/);
```

Source: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/8d1bd4a2-455e-4e3f-8c88-7ed49aeabc09/messagebox-is-not-applicationmodal?forum=wpf

Hopefully this is helpful to somebody else in the future!

Answer (score 0):

If this works in WPF like in Windows Forms you could just use:

```
MessageBox.ShowDialog()
```

chris

Above not working...

Edit:

But there is a workaround: style a Form like a MessageBox (use a fixed Border-Type) and then Show it using ShowDialog(). Then set the Forms Cacel and Ok Button in Properties to your Buttons and you can get a DialogResult just like in a MessageBox. Hope that Helps but it is also from Windows-Forms ;)

Comment: There isn't a MessageBox.ShowDialog() method in either WPF or WinForms.

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry, I was sure it was there ;) But there is a workaround: style a Form like a MessageBox (use a fixed Border-Type) and then Show it using ShowDialog(). Then set the Forms Cacel and Ok Button in Properties to your Buttons and you can get a DialogResult just like in a MessageBox. Hope that Helps but it is also from Windows-Forms ;)

Comment: @ChristophervonBlum That will result in the same behavior the OP is seeing; the `Show` method of a `MessageBox` *is* already a modal dialog.